# Query. Need to JOIN a created Data Extension with the same records from ET Subscriber

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions

I'm looking to add a field (LAST_OPENED) to a Data Extensions I created.

ET Subscriber has the records with all the fields needed but I was passed a list with out the (LAST_OPENED) field, I want to JOIN the two so the QUERY matches the records in ET Subscriber to the ones in my Data Extensions and adds (LAST_OPENED) as a result.

Here is the query I tried:

```
SELECT
t.*
FROM    
(SELECT A.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A.[LAST_OPENED] ORDER BY A.[LAST_OPENED]) as rn 
FROM Ent.[ET Subscriber] A
INNER JOIN [B_Med_Invitations_Audience20170531] B ON A.[LAST_OPENED] = B.[LAST_OPENED]

)  as t 
WHERE   t.rn = 1
```

Comment: What error / undesired result is it giving you?

Comment: If B_Med_Invitations_Audience does not have the Last_Opened field then joining them on that will not return any results

Comment: You're dealing with `datetime` datatypes, so the join would only work if both dates have the exact same times.

Comment: Did this work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, it would appear that you are trying to join on a field that is not common between the two data extensions. Your query would therefore return no results.

For the sake of this exercise, I will assume the following.

1. The [ET Subscriber] is an enterprise level DE
2. [ET Subscriber] and [B_Med_Invitations_Audience] have a common field (id).
3. You cannot PARTITION BY and ORDER BY the same variable

Try this:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM   (SELECT B.*, 
               Row_number() 
                 OVER ( 
                   partition BY A.[last_opened] 
                   ORDER BY A.id) AS rn, 
               A.[last_opened] 
        FROM   ent.[et subscriber] A 
               INNER JOIN [b_med_invitations_audience20170531] B 
                       ON A.id = B.id) AS t 
WHERE  t.rn = 1
```